# how to get photos of facebook group, as uploaded by people other than group admins? (via JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm building a website for a group that mirrors a facebook group, and I'd like to pull any photos of the group from facebook and display them on my site. BUT the photos might be uploaded by perfect strangers: so basically, a random person takes a picture of the group and uploads it to facebook, and we want that photo to be visible on our website.

I could think of three ways to do this:

1. **tag the photo as the group and find all photos tagged as the group**

   It seems you can't get Graph API access to photos tagged as a particular group (please prove me wrong). I can do this in FQL: `SELECT images FROM photo WHERE pid in (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=GROUP_ID)`, but from what I can tell, this requires the website visitor to log into facebook to create a FB session, which is no good.
2. **'share' the photo on our FB Page and somehow find all photos we've shared on our page**

   I can't seem to think of a way to restrict a search of shared objects to photos, but I'm open to suggestions.
3. **re-upload the photo ourselves into a group-controlled photo album**

   meh. The first two options don't involve creating any new objects on facebook, and would be preferred, but I'm having a hard time doing either of them, which leaves me with downloading the photos from facebook and uploading them all over again in our own photo album, which I know how to show.

Please tell me there's a better way to do it than #3?

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a little PHP app which turned my Facebook news feed (/me/home) into RSS, and make it possible to subscribe by Google Reader. Although my project has nothing to do with publishing, I think you'll need some similar technique with the offline_access I've used there.

So, first of all, you'll need dummy Facebook user account which have the permission to read and publish in the group (since that's a public group so save you from some trouble)

Get the access_token of this user with "offline_access" and other scopes required for publishing like direct url example here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Then... hard code the access token into the PHP script

```
$access_token = the access token from oauth;
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

Therefor, this script would act as that user. Anyone browsing the mirrored website doesn't even need a Facebook account.

After solving the authentication issue, the rest just simple coding for querying, uploading, publishing. Hope this would help

Comment: I'm not using PHP, so I'm not using the PHP facebook api, but I appreciate the suggestion. Still looking for a JavaScript-based answer.

Comment: I think you can, but not recommended. Because the access token will be exposed, and JS could react tricky in different browser. You'll still need to get an access token like above first. Not sure is there a function in their JS API to set access token, but jQuery would be a good choice via the $.get() function with 'jsonp' enabled.

Comment: Oh wait... I have to say this is STRONGLY NOT RECOMMENDED. Because people can use code injection from JS console to mess with the dummy account. (I've just tested with firebug and sadly the injection worked...) I'm not sure if just taking off the publish right would avoid this threat.

Comment: instead of a dummy account, I have an app, and it has very limited permissions... I asked a separate question http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8124279/how-safe-is-it-to-expose-an-access-token-to-the-client "how safe is it to expose an access token to the client?" and I haven't gotten a definitive answer, but from what I understand, there's nothing dangerous happening here.